# Failing to resize partition with diskutil

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, diskutil

I wish to resize my main macOS (High Sierra, HFS+) partition to use free space on the disk. I use console in Recovery Mode, as I suspect I won't be able the change the disk in use in standard mode. I however still cannot resize the partition, as the **system seems to fail to decide whether it is or not a coreStorage partition**:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list disk0
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage macOS                   20.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
-bash-3.2# diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 limits
Resize limits for partition disk0s2:
  Current partition size on map:              20.0 GB (19999997952 Bytes)
  Minimum size (constrained by file usage):   14.4 GB (14392414208 Bytes)
  Recommended minimum size (if used for OS):  19.8 GB (19761123328 Bytes)
  Maximum size (constrained by map space):    999.3 GB (999344099328 Bytes)
-bash-3.2# diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 R
Disk is a Core Storage Physical Volume (use a diskutil coreStorage verb instead to resize)
-bash-3.2# diskutil coreStorage resizeVolume disk0s2 R
disk0s2 does not appear to be a valid Core Storage Logical Volume UUID or disk
```

Ideally, I would like to keep the Recovery partition at the end of the physical disk, and the macOS partition to use all the space left. Any idea how I could solve this?

I add here other disks (but still skipping the myriad of disks following, as I am in Recovery Mode) and `diskutil cs list`:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list | head -n 19
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage macOS                   20.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS macOS                  +19.6 GB    disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 4F9A836A-6B15-4AEE-A4D7-51D0492069DF
                                 Unencrypted

-bash-3.2# diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group A341966B-0864-44D2-9C72-821608B2DE0E
    =========================================================
    Name:         macOS
    Status:       Online
    Size:         19999997952 B (20.0 GB)
    Free Space:   18989056 B (19.0 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 89AB7F23-DE06-46B3-953B-C38B15A3D3E2
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     19999997952 B (20.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 334245CF-35A1-42E8-AFBF-4EFE14DD2E9A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 4F9A836A-6B15-4AEE-A4D7-51D0492069DF
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          19628687360 B (19.6 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               macOS
            Volume Name:           macOS
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: Can you add the entirety of `diskutil list` & `diskutil cs list`?

Comment: Try entering `diskutil cs resizestack 4F9A836A-6B15-4AEE-A4D7-51D0492069DF 0` while booted to (standard mode) macOS.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In **standard boot** (NOT Recovery):

```
diskutil cs resizestack 4F9A836A-6B15-4AEE-A4D7-51D0492069DF 0
```